# Get better conclusions from a javascript randomizer

Tags: javascript, random

I have a simple javascript randomizer that compares two random numbers with values 1 to 6.

I want to get a good estimate about the probability of the first been greater than the second. I could do it using math, probability theory e.t.c. but lets say that I want to stick to javascript. Using millions or billions of itterations gives better estimates but I can't push that too far (especially since codepen, jsFiddle e.t.c. don't allow that many). Am I missing something? Is there a better way to estimate this probability? Right now, I just run the program (with 1000 itterations) a couple of times and calculate the average value but that gives values in quite a wide range, I'd like to get more restricted results.

```js
var xIsGreater = 0;
var yIsGreater = 0;
for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  ;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1  ;
  if(x>y){
    xIsGreater++;
  }else if(y>x){
    yIsGreater++;
  }
}
var draw = 1000-xIsGreater-yIsGreater;
console.log(xIsGreater+'--'+yIsGreater+'--'+draw);
```

Comment: Your current code can run a million iterations on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ykz2x7s/) in 37ms. Don't understand what you mean by "don't allow that many".

Comment: You're right, I didn't state that but my code actually does more things inside the loop (creates and suffles some arrays based on the random numbers) and that's the case (both codepen and jsFiddle stuck) with even just 10000 itterations.

Comment: If it does more things, we'd like to have those things in the review.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer, unfortunatelly I am not allowed to present this piece of code, but trust me, it's just some simple -yet a bit heavy- calculations with arrays. I just want to find other sollutions, past the 'increase the itterations' option.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` should be adequate for most pseudo-random use cases that don't need to be cryptographically secure.

You can consider using `RandomSource.getRandomValues()` ([MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues)) for a a more random distribution, but this may also come at the cost of more resources being utilized in generating the random number.

You may also have cross-browser compatibility issues as this is newer javascript API.

Comment: I'll definatelly check that out

Comment: Is Web API a library provided by Microsoft? Do I have to include it like some jQuery or how does it work?

Comment: @mizech If you mean the Web Cryptogrophy API, then it is built-in in newer browsers.  Check of the link I gave, it gives browser compatibility information. There are also polyfill libraries such as PolyCript - http://polycrypt.net/ if you need a library to potentially work in older browsers.